# How to run SocWatch with OpenMPI programming?

Tags: c++, mpi, energy

I try to measure energy consumption on my system with an openMPI program.

For OpenMPI, we can rut with `mpirun -n 4 ./hello`

This program will print `hello` from 4 processes.

Now, If it is a C++ program, we can run SocWatch with it as `sudo socwatch -m -f sys -f wakelock -t 35 -p ./hello`

With OpenMpi, I try `sudo socwatch -m -f sys -f wakelock -t 35 -p mpirun -n 4 ./hello`, But the program is stropped because socwatch did not recognize to mpi-run.

How to run SoCWatch with MPI?

If not, Is there any program can measure energy consumption on Linux.

Comment: Try with `mpirun` instead of `mpi-run`. I'm not aware of any MPI implementation that names its process launcher `mpi-run` with a dash in the middle.

Comment: Yes. This is my mistake when typing command. However, When I run it on my server, I use ```mpirun```

Comment: I guess `mpirun` is in your `$PATH` as a user, but is no more in your `$PATH` when `sudo` is used. try using the absolute path to `mpirun` instead. Note you will need to pass the `--allow-run-as-root` option to `mpirun`

Answer (score 1):

For SocWatch, the first parameter is the program, and the others are parameters for the program.

> sudo socwatch -m -f sys -f wakelock -t 35 -p [program] [parameters for program]